# Setting RAW16 data to display as UUID in an Oracle database in DBeaver

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I have a read-only access to an Oracle database. This database holds multiple schemas with multiple tables holding multiple RAW16 columns, all holding UUIDs.

Currently, DBeaver is displaying them as continuous strings, for example:

```
563C6E9D5A16489788DC06B41B465A7E
```

This affects browsing and searching for data. I need DBeaver to interpret RAW16 as lowercase UUID, just like it is in the PostgreSQL version of the database for example:

```
563c6e9d-5a16-4897-88dc-06b41b465a7e
```

While one can manually set each column to transform to UUID (for a single session), there are literally hundreds of them, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

`RAW(16)` is just 16-bytes of binary data, it is not specific to a UUID (that just happens to be what you are storing in the column).

If you want to format the binary data with a specific formatting then convert the column to a formatted string:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         LOWER(uuid),
         '^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$',
         '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5'
       ) AS uuid
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (uuid RAW(16));

INSERT INTO table_name (uuid) VALUES ( HEXTORAW('563C6E9D5A16489788DC06B41B465A7E') );
```

Outputs:

| UUID |
| --- |
| 563c6e9d-5a16-4897-88dc-06b41b465a7e |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LbnsomhT)

Comment: That is not exactly an answer. I am not interested in displaying the data in specific SQL queries, I'm interested in DBeaver displaying the data properly in its data browser. Like I've said, there are hundreds of tables and columns.

Comment: @Petersaber It is an answer as a client application (i.e. DBeaver) cannot know that a `RAW(16)` is a UUID and you want to format it with a specific formatting; the column could just be a 16-byte binary field that should not be formatted as a UUID. If you want to format it in a specific way then you need to explicitly tell the client application that you want to use a specific formatting for that column. You have said that you don't want to manually set the formatting using the client application so that leaves explicitly formatting the data in the query as an alternate option.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it by

right click on the column -> view/format -> Set "colun_name" -> UUID

Answer (score -1):

You can change it in configuration

Database -> Resultset -> Binaries

Or, for anyone using 4.3.5, this option is under Preferences -> Result Sets

Source:
Source: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1672

[image]

Comment: This is what makes it appear as '408BE63091194423ABFA4D009452D4DC' instead of gibberish, yes, but that's already where I am.